# Establishing serial port communication between Arduino and Godot?

Tags: arduino, godot

I’m wondering how do I go about establishing a serial port communication between Arduino Uno (as my input) and Godot game engine (as my output)? Context is, I'm trying to use sensors on Arduino to move/place objects on Godot, thus I need the serial port code or guidance on how to go about achieving that connection.

Any help is appreciated, thank you everyone!

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but potentially spanning several technologies. Does Godot have any direct arduino support? If so, include that in your question. If not, you would need a generic input solution. Godot probably has an input library of some sort, so apart from mouse and keyboard, does that include anything else? My gut says it won't tho. So you might just need to look for "how do I get input from arduino into C++" and accept that godot won't help you with this. Good luck in either case, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

You can try plugin [GDSerCommPlugin](https://github.com/NangiDev/GDSerCommPlugin). But it is work in progress and i didnt test it so i dont know if it is usable.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a long time this question was asked, I think that an update is welcome.
Since Godot 3.0, C# is fully supported, I'm using Godot 3.3.2 and my conclusion about dealing with serial communication in Godot is : **use C#**

You'll keep all the multi platform development advantage of Godot without writing a single (low level) line of code, here is a snipped:

```
using System.IO.Ports; // for .NET SerialPort
```

Then in your class if you want to open the port (assuming "SerialPort port" is defined):

```
port = new SerialPort(portName, (Int32)baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

**Then use the _Process to read the data**:

```
public override void _Process(float delta)
{
    if (port != null)
    {
        if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            string serData = port.ReadExisting();
            string[] str = serData.Split('\n'); // Just an example
            parseLines(str); // Your implementation
        }
    }
}
```

*Note1:* "DataReceived" event from SerialPort doesn't work (I don't know why but I think this is due to the different context) but with Godot this function is useless since you can check and parse directly the data in the _Process function.

*Note2:* For efficiency it's better to use the ReadExisting() function (and parse lines yourself) than the Readline() function in a loop in the _Process function.

*Note3:* Sending to serial port is immediate eg:

```
port.Write("Hello\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Ports on C# is not multiplatform and only works on windows, I have not tried GDSerialcommPlugin but i have tested https://github.com/matrixant/serial_port and it works on windows and linux.